# How to check that jQuery methods (fadeOut, hide, etc) have been called with Jasmine

Tags: jquery, tdd, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to clean up my Javascript by employing the same TDD methods that work for me in Ruby, but the jump to Jasmine has been throwing me for a curve.

For a simple example, I'd like to specify that a given element fades out on click:

```
$('.position-details').live 'click', ->
  $this = $(this)
  $this.fadeOut 'fast', ->
    $this.closest('.fields').find('.position-search').fadeIn('fast').focus()
```

My specs:

```
describe "Position picker", ->
  beforeEach ->
    loadFixtures("position_picker.html")
    @details = $('.position-details')
    @picker = $('.position-picker')
    jasmine.Clock.useMock()

  it "the position details are initially shown", ->
    expect(@details).toBeVisible()

  describe "when the position details are clicked", ->
    it "fades out the position details", ->
      @details.trigger('click')
      jasmine.Clock.tick(1000)
      expect(@details).not.toBeVisible()
```

My fixture:

```
<div id='position-data' data-positions="[{&quot;value&quot;:35,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Accountant&quot;,&quot;division&quot;:&quot;North&quot;,&quot;job_class&quot;:&quot;Headquarters&quot;}]"></div>

<div class='position-details'>
  <div class='position-name'></div>
  <br />
</div>

<div class='position-picker'>
  <label>Position<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
  <span class="error" />
  <input class="position-search" type="text" />
  <div>
    <input class="position_id" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The first spec passes and I'm not sure why the second doesn't. Once I get a few of these under my belt I'm sure it'll feel second nature. Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: Why you wanna test that the element is invisible. Your code is not liable for this, but jquery. So if there is a bug in jquery your test will fail, even if your code is correct. All you should test is that on click the function are called to your element.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't want to test that jquery works, but that I've written code that calls fadeOut, because the element is supposed to fade. I imagine that semantically I'm not testing this the correct way, but I can't find examples of the way I _should_ be testing this. My code is liable to call fadeOut if it's supposed to fade still. There's just a different way to do this I'm not getting and it isn't the code above.

Comment: Take look at this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8526477/184883 and this blog post http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/04/26/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-3.html

Comment: @AndreasKöberle this comment is so helpful. If you reword this as an answer I will accept it. It truly is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8526477/184883) and this [blog post](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/04/26/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-3.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spyOn`

check this:

```js
it("fades out the element", function() {
  spyOn($.fn, 'fadeOut');
  fadeOutElem();
  expect($.fn.fadeOut).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Also you can use a timeout like this:

```js
it("fades out the element", function(done) {
  fadeOutElem();
  setTimeout(300, function() {
    expect($(".position-details").css('display').toEqual('none');
    done();
  });
});
```