# jasmine and backbone and js templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

Hi, I'm attempting to use jasmine headless webkit: http://johnbintz.github.com/jasmine-headless-webkit/

I've been embedding js templates inside of my app's main HTML file. My app is starting to get rather complex and I thought I could use jasmine to give it some more test coverage. Since my views reference javascript templates that are in my main HTML file, my views will error out. Is there some way to get around this? Can I somehow reproduce the state of my app's HTML file? Ie, load all its js templates, and load the vendor javascripts in the correct order in the head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can add your template files to your jasmine test runner page.

Another solution would be to mock out your views DOM element. You could insert the element in the constructor like `new View({el: $($('myTemplate').html())})`. Doing so, you can add an element mock or spy in your test, with no need to create DOM element based on your template:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    el = {bind: function(){}};
    spyOn(el, 'bind');
    var OrderListView = new OrderSumView({el: el, model: model});
});

it('it should render the sum after firing the remove event', function() {

    //test that bind('click', someFunction) was called to your element
    expect(el.bind).toHaveBeenCalledWith('click', model.bind.argsForCall[0][1]);

    // fire up the function that was bind to the click event
    el.bind.argsForCall[0][1]() 
})
```

With this solution you can totally mock out html in the most cases. Its the way we test our large GWT application. Its much easier with GWT than with backbone cause we are in the JAVA world, but the principle is the same. Dont test the DOM, just test your business logic. If done it this way for my private backbone project and it works well.

Take also a look at this SO: [Stub out a jQuery selector call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8523974/184883)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andreas, but I partially disagree with you. Since Backbone is by design a front-end framework, we expect the most part of core/business logic to be handled server-side, though API calls eg.
In this configuration, my point is we should only write integration tests, in order to check the correct data display client-side. I might have misunderstood something, but I think you have to test the DOM element, and not only the status of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can load html fixtures in your jasmine specs. See: https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery

```
loadFixtures('myfixture.html');
$('#my-fixture').myTestedPlugin();
expect($('#my-fixture')).to...;
```

Anyway you can check my sample project with backbone.js and jasmine: https://github.com/lucassus/tdd-with-backbonejs and check how I'm using this technique in the real life.
Also I'm going to write blog post about testing backbone's views with jasmine: http://blog.bandzarewicz.com