# jasmine test - mock element html

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I want to write test to my JS script. 
I have on my HTML page input element, which receives values through user.
My JS script gets this values and creates JSON object.

HTML

```
<input name="test1" type="text" id="inputWord1">
<input name="test2" type="text" id="inputWord2">
```

JS script

```
var myFun = function(){
    var data = {};
    data.first = $('#inputWord1').val();
    data.second = $('#inputWord2').val();
    return data;
}
```

In my script Jasmine I would like to simulate data input.

I suppose, that I should mock html element in Jasmine.
The html element will be fake input data.

But, I don't know how implement this in Jasmine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stub out a jQuery selector call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523974/stub-out-a-jquery-selector-call)